# Bulk Update not updating values in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to perform a quick update to a large collection I have, consisting of objects looking like this:

```
{_id: 0, 'Name': 'Bob'}
```

Here I am attempting to perform a bulk update. The reason I am using the bulk loop and not the 'update_many' command is eventually my update for a particular id might have a different name, so I need to change the values that I am passing in set

```
bulk = myTable.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
counter = 0
i = 1
while(i < 100000):
    bulk.find({ '_id': i }).update({ '$set': { 'Name': 'N' } })
    i += 1
    counter += 1

    if (counter % 500 == 0):
        bulk.execute()
        bulk = myTable.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

if(counter % 500 != 0):
    bulk.execute()
```

However when I run this code, there are no changes to the table, and every entry still has the name 'Bob'

Any idea how I would correct this? Am I somehow not committing? Eventually my goal is to be able to bulk update quickly, but pass values like

```
$set: { 'Name' : Names[i] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why you are not using something like this?

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne
i = 1
commands = []
while(i < 100000):
    i += 1
    command = UpdateOne({"_id": i}, { "$set": { "Name": "N" } })
    commands.append(command)
    if (len(commands) == 1000):
        myTable.bulk_write(commands, ordered=False)
        commands = []
if(len(commands) != 0):
    myTable.bulk_write(commands, ordered=False)
```

This should solve your problem.